# Ensuring a down pipe attached to a wall stays elevated above the ground

Tags: pvc, downspout

I have a downpipe that I noticed was full of water. When I lifted it up, all the water started gushing out. The attachments had come off and it had slipped down leading me to believe it was sitting tight against the ground blocking the flow. I will replace the attachments but I'm not sure if it will slide down again causing the same problem

[image: downpipe in the background sitting on the ground]

Suggestions as to how to get it to stay elevated that would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Put screw in the lower pipe to stop the down pipe from dropping down.

Answer (score 2):

Replace that pipe clamp with one that *isn't* broken. You can, most likely, simply use the original screw holes (whether into wooden siding above that stone veneer foundation wall, or into plastic/lead inserts into stone/brick above where we can see).

If you need to, put a dab of caulk into the old holes to prevent water ingress and drill new ones for the new pipe clamp.